Question: Batch Transaction Authentication by Optimism Batcher
I am reading the optimism derivation spec here
In this section Batcher Transaction Format there is this comment that I can't fully grasp:

Batch transactions are authenticated by verifying that the to address of the transaction matches the batch inbox address, and the from address matches the batch-sender address in the system configuration at the time of the L1 block that the transaction data is read from.

Assume that a batch transaction was submitted at time T0 and sometime later it is being read by L2 -- and it being constructed as L2 blocks -- at time T1 (T1 > T0)
Referring to the quotation above, T1 is: "the time of the L1 block that the transaction data is read from"
How can a transaction that was formatted and submitted way before T1 (at time T0) carry the address of the batcher sometime in the future?
Or are the batcher addresses always remain the same? Which makes the part of specification about "the time of the L1 block..." very inaccurate.

I think the reason might be this. Reading the same source under the Architecture section I found this:
(L1 Traversal)[https://specs.optimism.io/protocol/derivation.html#l1-traversal]

Upon traversal of the L1 block, the system configuration copy used by the L1 retrieval stage is updated, such that the batch-sender authentication is always accurate to the exact L1 block that is read by the stage.

Which shows prior to Retrieval the address is updated from the block.

I hate the fact that the Comments section formatting is different from the main section
